# Text goes out of map in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

Faced the following problem. I have a ListView where the cards are stacked and when I have a long text it disappears outside of the card where I cut the card with ClipPath. I suspect that the problem is that I'm using Stack, but if without it I don't know how to place the button in the upper right corner. I attached a screenshot below and showed how my text gets out of the card and I need it to wrap to a new line. How can I make text always visible and move it to a new line if it doesn't fit on one line?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Expanded(
      child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: nearby.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) => Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(bottom: index == nearby.length - 1 ? 80 : 0),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: Stack(
                // fit: StackFit.loose,
                children: [
                  ClipPath(
                    clipper: OrderCardClipper(right: 0, holeRadius: 60),
                    child: Container(
                      width: size.width,
                      height: 247,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: constants.Colors.greyXDark.withOpacity(0.5),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: _content(context, index),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 7,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        _directionButton(),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _content(BuildContext context, index) => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 10,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    _stationImage(),
                    const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 12,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: _stationInfoWidget(index),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 0.2,
              height: 10,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 2),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: nearby.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) => Container(
                height: 32,
                width: 32,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  nearby.keys.elementAt(index),
                  width: 12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 2),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 0.2,
              height: 10,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Flexible(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: Text(
                          '0.13 JC/KWh',
                          style: constants.Styles.normalHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 36,
                        width: 147,
                        child: DefaultButtonGlow(
                          shadowColor: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                          text: 'Book Again',
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                          borderColor: Colors.transparent,
                          textStyle: constants.Styles.buttonTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

  Widget _stationImage() {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 4,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 90,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/background/splash_background_logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _stationInfoWidget(index) => Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Andy K. Station lorem i',
            style: constants.Styles.bigLtStdRomanTextStyleWhite,
          ),
          Text(
            '21 Yohansburg Blvd, Oslo',
            style: constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite
                .copyWith(color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
          ),
```

This is how part of the text disappears, but it needs to be transferred

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot below where it is shown that the text is out of bounds, but it needs to move to a new line

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in a stack the latter widget will always be rendered on top of the others. In order to achieve your expected result, for a simple solution you could just change the ClipPath width to

```
size.width - (size of direction button + its padding and margin )
```

But a better solution would be not to use stack, and layout everything in rows and columns, and use Flexible / Expanded wherever you need the widget to take the space needed. For example :

```
Column(
  children: [ 
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: YourTitle()),
        DirectionButton(),
      ]),
the rest of the widgets ...
```

Comment: I'll try and give you an answer.